# Defacements on borderless form when form is resizing

Tags: vb.net

I am working on vb project and I have make a custom borderless form with custom title bar and status bar. My problem is when I resize my form. I am getting some defacements. Please take a look [here](https://youtu.be/Kt-Fzjx8Rug). Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Painting is optimized for container controls, like Form, on the assumption that they don't do any fancy painting themselves.  Only the part of the window that is revealed by the resize is painted.  Won't work here, you need to add `Me.ResizeRedraw = True` in the form constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling the `DoubleBuffered` property

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It works for main form but not for MDI child forms...

Comment: I'm not sure because I can't test but on the resize event Invalidate the control, forcing it to redraw. You might get flicker, not sure. controlName.Invalidate()

Comment: Can you give me an example?